# Unable to add attributes to links in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the format of various links on my webpage. Links can be any of these types:

```
<a data-id="1444709976-ohgusB" data-toggle="modal" class="modal-link store-link" 
   href="http://firstwebsite.com/some-text.html" 
   data-target="#myModal">
   BOLDR Voyage watch may just be the “clever” device you want and need</a>

<a data-id="1443322807-iLmF2d" class="store-link" 
   href="http://secondwebsite.com/other-text.html" target="_blank">
   Gmail for Android: 7 cool tips and tricks you must try<span class="fa fa-external-link"></span></a>
```

I tried using following jQuery to change attributes of all links that have only `.store-link` class. This is my code:

```
if($('a.store-link').hasClass('modal-link')==false){
  $(this).removeAttr('target');
  $(this).addClass('modal-link');
  $(this).attr('data-toggle','modal');
  $(this).attr('data-target','#myModal');
}
```

However, there is no change in attributes of any link. I don't get any error either.

Comment: "However, there is no change in attributes of any link." — How are you testing this?

Comment: @Archer — Not true. A DOM inspector should show the change.

Comment: Your code example is incomplete. You haven't shown us enough to tell what `this` is.

Comment: Learn to debug. Look at `console.log(this)` and `console.log($('a.store-link').hasClass('modal-link'))`see why.

Comment: @Quentin I check the source code in DOM Inspector.

Comment: If there is at least one link with class `modal-link` in the DOM the `if` condition will never be fulfilled

Comment: @SanJeetSingh — The DOM inspector doesn't show source code. It shows a representation of the DOM.

Comment: @Quentin , Thanks for the correction :).

Comment: @Quentin my bad.  I'm thinking of using `data()` to change the value, rather than `attr()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use each it will loop on all a.store-link and it will work , 
on your code you have some mistakes like the `$(this)` , that i think you think it refers to `$("a.store-link")` but it's not

```
$('a.store-link').each(function()
{
   if($(this).hasClass('modal-link') == false)
   {
      $(this).removeAttr('target');
      $(this).addClass('modal-link');
      $(this).attr('data-toggle','modal');
      $(this).attr('data-target','#myModal');
   }
});
```

Comment: This is right answer, why down vote? $(this) was problem in OP, because it is not defined actually, this code works fine.

Comment: yea :'( some times it happens :p

Comment: should i explain ? because i gave a working code , i will add explanation

Comment: You really should store `$(this)` in a variable instead of creating five instances, or use chaining. And use `.data()` to change a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: yea , but in this case i just added $('a.store-link').each(function()
{}); to his code

Comment: @Diptox I have one doubt. Why was `$("a.store-link")` not `$(this)` in my code snippet?

Comment: i did not understand your question

Answer (score 2):

As an explanation for @Diptox's answer, I added this answer.

In a function space if you don't set `this` object, it would point to the global object (i.e. `window` object) unless you call a function and set it's `this` object or call a function in a literal object.

In the example below, multiple usage of `this` has been written.

```
var foo = /* some object */;

function bar (){
    console.log(this);
}

var obj = {
    someMethod: function(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}

console.log(this); // this = Global Object i.e. window
bar();             // this = Global Object i.e. window
bar.call(foo);     // this = foo
obj.someMethod();  // this = obj
```

---

In your case:

```
if($('a.store-link').hasClass('modal-link')==false){
    $(this).removeAttr('target');
    $(this).addClass('modal-link');
    $(this).attr('data-toggle','modal');
    $(this).attr('data-target','#myModal');
}
```

Actually `this` points to the global object (i.e. `window`). While in @Diptox's answer:

```
$('a.store-link').each(function()
{

   /* In this function space, 'this' is set by jQuery,          */
   /* which points to the current object of type 'a.store-link' */

   if($(this).hasClass('modal-link') == false)
   {
       $(this).removeAttr('target');
       $(this).addClass('modal-link');
       $(this).attr('data-toggle','modal');
       $(this).attr('data-target','#myModal');
   }
});
```